# How to simulate time costly operations using PHP?

Tags: php, performance, simulation, sleep

My current project using `PHP`
And we decided to simulate the behavior of final project
There are some blocks of codes which expected to consume more time
Like applying some algorithms before INSERT/UPDATE to database and so on

So when try to simulate and write some stubs
Till now we use `sleep($seconds)` function

Is that is right or there is another alternative due to any side affects because of using `sleep($seconds)` function

Comment: It can help but what if you get an error like memory exhausted?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi - also sadly database connections has gone away